# Error in the result of matrix multiplication example of CUDA C programming guide

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, matrix-multiplication

I'm doing the matrix multiplication example from the book CUDA C Programming Guide, page 35, for practice, I copied the code and completed the missing code. I understand the logic of the program and how it should work, but I get no the expected result.

Here is the complete code i made, I do not know if the error is mine or from the example?

The code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16

typedef struct
{
    int width;
    int height;
    float *elements;
}Matrix;

__global__ void MatMulKernel(const Matrix,const Matrix, Matrix C);

void MatMul(const Matrix A,const Matrix B, Matrix C) 
{
    size_t size;
    //Matrix A creation y storage in device memory 
    Matrix d_A;
    d_A.width=A.width;
    d_A.height=A.height;
    size=A.height*A.width*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_A.elements,size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_A.elements,A.elements,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Matrix B creation y storage in device memory 
    Matrix d_B;
    d_B.width=B.width;
    d_B.height=B.height;
    size=B.height*B.width*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_B.elements,size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B.elements,B.elements,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Matrix C creation y storage in device memory         
    Matrix d_C;
    d_C.width=C.width;
    d_C.height=C.height;
    size=C.height*C.width*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_C.elements,size);
    //        
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 dimGrid(B.width/dimBlock.x,A.height/dimBlock.y);
    MatMulKernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_A,d_B,d_C);
    //Copy the result in the matrix C from the device to the host.        
    cudaMemcpy(C.elements,d_C.elements,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);  
    //edit the missing code.
    // for(int i=0;i<BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE;i++){cout<<C.elements[i]<<endl;}      
    // result in random numbers
    cudaFree(d_A.elements);
    cudaFree(d_B.elements);
    cudaFree(d_C.elements);
}

__global__ void MatMulKernel(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C)
{
    float Cvalue=0;
    int row=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    int col=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    for(int e=0;e<A.width;++e)
    {
        Cvalue+=A.elements[row*A.width+e]*B.elements[e*B.width+col];
    }
    C.elements[row*C.width+col]=Cvalue;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Matrices"<<endl;
    //Declarationd of the A,B,C matrix´s
    float a[15][15];        
    float b[15][15];
    float c[15][15];
    //Fill the matrix whit some numbers.
    int cont0=0;
    for(int c=0;c<15;c++)
    {
        for(int v=0;v<15;v++)
        {
            a[v][c]=cont0;
            b[v][c]=cont0;
            cont0++;
        }
    }
    //Flatten the matrix for the passing to the kernel
    int offset=0;
    float a_t[256];
    float b_t[256];
    for(int y=0;y<15;y++)
    {                        
        for(int x=0;x<15;x++)
        {
            a_t[x+offset]=a[x][y];
            b_t[x+offset]=a[x][y];
        }
        offset=offset+15;
    }
    float t_C[256];
    //Completing the matrix format for the kernel.
    Matrix m_A;
    m_A.height=15;
    m_A.width=15;
    m_A.elements=a_t;
    Matrix m_B;
    m_B.height=15;
    m_B.width=15;
    m_B.elements=b_t;
    Matrix m_C;
    m_C.height=15;
    m_C.width=15;
    m_C.elements=t_C;
    //Passing the formated matrix to the kernel.
    MatMul(m_A,m_B,m_C);                
    cout<<"Final"<<endl;        
return 0;
}
```

The program compiles and runs but the result matrix `C.elements` from:     `cudaMemcpy(C.elements,d_C.elements,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);`
  is a random number. I've tried to use it like a pointer to a array but i don't get anything from it and treating it like array does not work either.

I will be glad if anyone can help me to finish this.

Comment: Your code is not doing anything with the result copied back to `m_C`, so how do you know the result is wrong?  Have you written code to print it out?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, i post the clean version of the code, i use a breakpoint in  cudaMemcpy(C.elements,d_C.elements,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); and a FOR to print the elements of C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has minor miss match between array indexing in kernel and initialization on CPU. Here is the corrected code with debugging suggested by @harrism:

```
    #include "cuda_runtime.h"
    #include "device_launch_parameters.h"
    #include "cuda_runtime.h"
    #include "device_launch_parameters.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    using namespace std;
    #define BLOCK_SIZE 16

    typedef struct
    {
        int width;
        int height;
        float *elements;
    }Matrix;

    __global__ void MatMulKernel(const Matrix,const Matrix, Matrix C);

    void MatMul(const Matrix A,const Matrix B, Matrix C)
    {
        size_t size;
        //Matrix A creation y storage in device memory
        Matrix d_A;
        d_A.width=A.width;
        d_A.height=A.height;
        size=A.height*A.width*sizeof(float);
        cudaMalloc(&d_A.elements,size);
        cudaMemcpy(d_A.elements,A.elements,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        //Matrix B creation y storage in device memory
        Matrix d_B;
        d_B.width=B.width;
        d_B.height=B.height;
        size=B.height*B.width*sizeof(float);
        cudaMalloc(&d_B.elements,size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B.elements,B.elements,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Matrix C creation y storage in device memory
    Matrix d_C;
    d_C.width=C.width;
    d_C.height=C.height;
    //cudaMalloc(&d_C,sizeof(Matrix));
    //cudaMemcpy(d_C,C,sizeof(Matrix),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    size=C.height*C.width*sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_C.elements,size);
    //
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 dimGrid(B.width/dimBlock.x,A.height/dimBlock.y);
    MatMulKernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_A,d_B,d_C);
    //Copy the result in the matrix C from the device to the host.
    printf("error code: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
    cudaMemcpy(C.elements,d_C.elements,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    //
    cudaFree(d_A.elements);
    cudaFree(d_B.elements);
    cudaFree(d_C.elements);
}

__global__ void MatMulKernel(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C)
{
        //printf("%d\n",threadIdx.x);
    float Cvalue=0;
    int row=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    int col=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    for(int e=0;e<A.width;++e)
    {
        Cvalue+=A.elements[row*A.width+e]*B.elements[e*B.width+col];
    }
    C.elements[row*C.width+col]=Cvalue;
}

int print_matrix(Matrix A){
        printf("Matrix:\n");
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<A.width*A.height; i++){
                if(i%A.width==0) printf("\n");
                printf("%6.4f\t",A.elements[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"Matrices"<<endl;
    //Declarationd of the A,B,C matrix.s
    float a[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    float b[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    float c[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
    //Fill the matrix whit some numbers.
    int cont0=0;
    for(int c=0;c<BLOCK_SIZE;c++)
    {
        for(int v=0;v<BLOCK_SIZE;v++)
        {
            a[v][c]=cont0;
            b[v][c]=cont0;
            cont0++;
        }
    }
    //Flatten the matrix for the passing to the kernel
    int offset=0;
    float a_t[BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE];
    float b_t[BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE];
    for(int y=0;y<BLOCK_SIZE;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<BLOCK_SIZE;x++)
        {
            a_t[x+offset]=a[x][y];
            b_t[x+offset]=a[x][y];
        }
        offset=offset+BLOCK_SIZE;
    }
    float t_C[BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE];
    //Completing the matrix format for the kernel.
    Matrix m_A;
    m_A.height=BLOCK_SIZE;
    m_A.width=BLOCK_SIZE;
    m_A.elements=a_t;
    Matrix m_B;
    m_B.height=BLOCK_SIZE;
    m_B.width=BLOCK_SIZE;
    m_B.elements=b_t;
    Matrix m_C;
    m_C.height=BLOCK_SIZE;
    m_C.width=BLOCK_SIZE;
    m_C.elements=t_C;
    //Passing the formated matrix to the kernel.
    print_matrix(m_A);
    print_matrix(m_B);
    MatMul(m_A,m_B,m_C);
    print_matrix(m_C);
    cout<<"Final"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Check the output. If you see the results are wrong, check the kernel error on your system which is reported in output.

Comment: t_C should be size BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE unless I misread. Good work though, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) for how to get useful answers to your questions. In particular, you should *always* check the return value of your CUDA API calls and kernel launches. Also, running `cuda-memcheck` can often be very helpful to detect out-of-bounds accesses like this.

@harrism asked how you know the result is wrong since you don't appear to do anything with it.

But more importantly you have 15x15 matrices being computed with a 16x16 threadblock, but you're not taking care to disable the out-of-bounds threads. Since you're trying to create a simple example, just increase the matrix size to 16x16 - if you want to handle odd sizes then you'll need to implement the control logic (or use cuBLAS!).

Comment: My mistake, I clean the code of comments and unused code before posting, I use a breackpoint and a FOR loop to print the contents of C.elements in MatMul.